# Captured cursor invisible with Centos 6.4 running on VMWare Player 3.1.6 on Ubuntu 11.4

Tags: vmware, centos

I have a very old (c. 2001) computer and the most recent version of Ubuntu that it can run is 11.4.  I am thinking of replacing Ubuntu with Centos 6.5 but am not sure if the hardware can handle it.  I am therefore trying to install Centos 6.4 on a virtual machine using VMWare Player 3.1.6.  I user VMWare Player to install CentOS-6.5-i386 from an ISO.  It appears to run successfully and I get a Centos login dialogue.  However, when I click on the login dialogue (or do control-G), the cursor disappears.  I tried reinstalling Centos and found that the same thing happens during the installation so I suspect the problem lies with VMWare Player rather than with Centos 6.5.  The keyboard also appears to have no effect when the cursor is captured.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like VMware is capturing focus on you and doesn't really have anything to do with CentOS.

You could try installing the VMwareTools which should allow for normal transitioning of your mouse and keyboard as the VM gains and loses focus. VMware has a knowledgebase article titled: [Installing VMware Tools in a Linux virtual machine using a Compiler (1018414)](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1018414).

If you're unable to get VMwareTools to install correctly you can manually download them from VMware for your particular application, VMware Player, and then copy them & install them manually into the VM.

All the VMware software, such as tools, etc. is accessible from this VMware URL:

- http://softwareupdate.vmware.com/cds/vmw-desktop/player/

You can back that URL off if you want a different product than Player as well. If you drill down into the URL for you particular version of Player you'll find the VMwareTools software down a couple of levels.

Comment: I followed the first 3 steps but it looks like I need a VMware Tools CD.  It does not say where I get that from.  When I initially started the player up with Centos, it asked me if I wanted to download and install the tools.  I said yes and it downloaded them and ran all night but I still do not appear to have the tools.  Tonight I clicker on VM:Install VMware Tools.  It now has the option to cancel the installation instead but does not show any progress.  Thanks,

Comment: @OtagoHarbour - if you have access to the VM I've often times had to go into the VM and use `scp` to copy the `.iso` file myself into it, mount it, and then run the installer manually. Player leaves you hanging, has been my experience in the pasat. You might also want to make use of VirtualBox instead, just a thought.